# Calling method with a button and bad GPS data

Tags: android, button, gps

I've an application that logs data from the start using a method. I also have a button that just shows a toast at the moment, but I would like that to start the logging.

The main question is, how do I start a method, using only the button?

Also my GPS puts me at -9, 53 which is in Tanzania. I am not in Tanzania, I'm along way away.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

**code**

```
 private OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The Start button was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    double Longitude = arg0.getLongitude();
    double Latitude = arg0.getLatitude();
    String Long = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(Longitude);
    String Lat = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(Latitude);
    location = Long + "," + Lat;
    locationText.setText(location);
}
```

Comment: please post your code!

Comment: why don't you just call the method you want to call from inside the onClick event?

Comment: thats just `logMethod();` is it?

Comment: Ah great. Its always simple :P do you know anything about my GPS problem?

Comment: do you have your gps on? I suppose you are indoors... try going outside and see if it works

Comment: Have it on, went outside, was same outcome. Location is set with GPS comes up on the phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer of question 2: you exchanged latitude and longitude, 53, -9 is near Limerick, Ireland.
For question 1: a basic tutorial will show you how to call a method triggered by a button click.

Comment: Oh ok, so ts supposed to be lat, long. That explains so much. Thanks. Its now showing where I am, well now that I looked up the gps coordinates of where. Thanks.